# Category Overlap Analysis

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to perform some category overlap analysis and need help.

I have data made up of customer service tickets. The tickets are labeled with category data. Tickets can contain multiple category labels.

I have a query that pulls ticket ids and categories. I get multiple rows for IDs with more than one category. I am looking for a way to show the category overlap, for example: how many tickets have category A, have A and B, B and C, etc..

I would like to be able to perform this in Excel or R so that it can easily be incorporated into reports for my management.

An example of my query output is as follows:

```
category  ticket_id

A   3975472 
D   3975472 
B   3975472 
P   3969484 
B   3969484 
S   3969484 
P   3968360 
C   3968360 
D   3964048 
A   3964048 
C   3963748 
E   3963748
```

Thank you!

I was hoping to achieve an output such as:

[image: desired_output]

Comment: Where would you like the overlaps? In the worksheet? As variables in code? Also, how many categories are there in total?

Comment: I imagined a worksheet that would give me the count of ids per category combination. I imagined the worksheet having the categories across the top row and then down the first column with the count of ids at the intersections. 


In reality there are ~400 categories.

Comment: Wow! 400 categories? So each of those is to be combined as a column heading to do the count for? That's 400^2 combinations. Excel only has 16384 columns in a worksheet. Maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: If you just want to list each category singly per row, then is there a reason the PivotTable answer already provided would not suffice?

Comment: I have added a screen shot with my desired output to my question. I apologize for my lack of ability in describing the desired output.

Comment: building on Jason's answer, to get your expected output try... 
`crossprod(table(df$ticket_id, df$category))`

Comment: Since each ticket can have 1 or more categories you need to decide how you want them counted. for example how would you deal with A   3975472 
D   3975472 
B   3975472 would it be counted for AA, AD, AB, DD, DB and BB

Comment: I would also assume the table you showed would have been symmetric. Any reason why its not symmetric or is that just random values you put in.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not exactly sure what you are after. Do the totals in your "hoping to achieve output" image actually represent what should come from your posted sample data?

Answer (score 3):

In `Excel` you could do this with a Pivot table:

[image: Pivot]

In `R`, assuming the data is in a data frame named `df`, you could do something like this:

```
table(df$ticket_id, df$category)
#         A B C D E P S
# 3963748 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
# 3964048 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
# 3968360 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
# 3969484 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
# 3975472 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: For R, `addmargins` and `zero.print` can be used to mimick the excel output: `print(addmargins(table(df$ticket_id, df$category)),zero.print="")`

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting question. Hope the code below provides the solution. I am using the library reshape2 for some data rearranging.

```
set.seed(1)
# creating a sample dataset
dat <- data.frame(category = sample(x = letters[1:6], size = 1000,replace = T), ticket = sample(x = 1000:1500, size = 1000,replace = T))
dat <- unique(dat)
dat <- dat[order(dat$ticket, dat$category),]
head(dat)

    category ticket
311        a   1000
916        c   1000
978        d   1000
949        f   1000
72         f   1001
597        c   1002

library(reshape2)

#same as table function but gives a data frame
tab <- dcast(dat,ticket ~ category, length)  

#create all possible 2-way combinations
levels <- sort(unique(dat$category))
combs <- data.frame(rows = rep(levels,times = length(levels)), cols = rep(levels,each = length(levels)))

#calculate count for each combination
combs$count <- apply(combs,1,function(x) sum(tab[,x[1]] & tab[,x[2]]))

overlap <- dcast(combs, rows ~ cols) #convert output into a square matrix

  rows   a   b   c   d   e   f
1    a 140  38  36  41  36  42
2    b  38 128  48  32  41  39
3    c  36  48 161  35  49  36
4    d  41  32  35 123  32  35
5    e  36  41  49  32 139  38
6    f  42  39  36  35  38 138
```

Let me know if any of this needs further explaining.